# how to make quad topo here?

Tags: modeling, topology

I can't figure out how to properly make quad topology here so that it is nice and smooth & pinching-free after sub-div surface modifier? Help plz c:
[image]

I am getting such shading errors (waves)
[image]

See the waves is it forming.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share your file so that we can test

Comment: @moonboots here ya go [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=jyo7Po20" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/jyo7Po20/)

Comment: I agree with Apec, probably better to use a 32 vertex cylinder instead

Answer (score 3):

In your case, IMO, like this to minimize stretch:
blue - good, red - bad curvature
[image]

But for good curvature need Cylinder with more (32) edges.

Comment: What would be your approach, other than increasing edges? I wish to know the right approach without increasing vert count too much

Comment: the "blue" way but without increasing Cylinder edges, nothing better comes to mind.

Comment: Okay... Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

The one solution i found for shading error is the DATA TRANSFER modifier. It fixed the shading issue.
[image]